# Wrapping interfaces in array

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I am working with interfaces array used to bind parametrized modules.
My problem is that I cannot directly concatenate several simple interfaces into an array of interfaces.

Here is a light version of the interface that I use:

```
interface channel ();
  wire req;
  wire ack;
  modport in (input req output ack);
  modport out(input ack output req);
endinterface
```

What I want to do would be:

```
Channel array[2]();
Channel elem0();
Channel elem1();

"assign" array = '{elem0,elem1};
```

I found a workaround using a module that assigns each wire independently:

```
module passthrough (Channel.in from, Channel.out to );
  assign to.req   = from.req;
  assign from.ack = to.ack;
endmodule
```

Using it, I have to 'cast' each member element into each array member. Using the previous example:

```
 passthrough pass0( .from(elem0), .to(array[0]));
 passthrough pass1( .from(elem1), .to(array[1]));
```

I do not like it though as the primary idea about using parametrized modules was to make my RTL clearer, shorter and maintainable.

I naturally put the instantiation of this `passthrough`module in a macro but still, I am not satisfied.

I then stumbled on tasks embeded in interfaces. Although I am not quite familiar with tasks in (S)Verilog so I do not think that my idea would work. Here is however what I tried:

```
interface channel ();
  reg req;
  reg ack;
  modport in (input req output ack);
  modport out(input ack output req);

  task wrap_from (Channel.in I);
    always@* begin
      req = I.req;
      I.ack = ack;
    end
  endtask
endinterface
```

The advantage of this method would be that I would not need to create a module each time I need to connect 2 channels. The code line would also be shorter.

Unfortunately, my compiler(ncsim) does not recognize `channel` as an interface inside the its own declaration(I guess it needs the `endinterface` keyword to consider it in the namespace).

I would be extremely grateful if anyone has a cleaner than solution than me for this problem.

One last thing, everything needs to be synthetisable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with why you want to unroll an array of interfaces. Why do elem0 and elem1 even exist? As suggested, there is no way to "assign" interfaces to each other. My recommendation is to just use Channel array[2] everywhere. You can bind to each instance and you can connect each to a module. Maybe if you shared to what you are trying to connect I could help out more?

I'm doubtful that module tasks are synthesizeable. That looks like a dead end to me.

Comment: See my edited post for more informations about what I do.
With precautions, tasks should be synthetisable.